# How to get events from transaction receipt in web3JS ( Solidity )

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I have tried using events.eventname.returnValues[index] but I am not getting any response. Below is the smart contract code -

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;

contract Dflip{

    uint contractBalance;
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier costs (uint cost){
        require(msg.value >= cost,"The minimum value to place bet is 0.01 ether");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    event flipCoinData(uint betValue,bool result);
    event withdrawFundData(uint amount);
    event fundContractData(address funder,uint fundAmount);

function flipCoin() public payable costs(0.1 ether) returns(bool)  {
    require(msg.value <= contractBalance,"The contract doesn't have enough balance");
  bool result;
  uint chance;
  chance = now % 2;
  if (chance == 0){
      contractBalance += msg.value;
    result = false;
  }
  else if ( chance == 1){
      contractBalance -= msg.value;
      msg.sender.transfer(msg.value*2);
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
  emit flipCoinData(msg.value,result);
}

function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}
function withdrawAll() public onlyOwner {
    emit withdrawFundData(contractBalance);
    msg.sender.transfer(contractBalance);

}
function fundContract() public payable {
    require(msg.value != 0);
    contractBalance += msg.value;
    emit fundContractData(msg.sender,msg.value);
}
}
```

And this is the mainJS file to connect with web3JS

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
var contractInstance;

$(document).ready(function(){
  window.ethereum.enable().then(function(accounts){
    contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,"0x28811FA3bC95f2776918871BAb6332662f15cd43",{from:accounts[0]})
    console.log(contractInstance);
  })

  $("#flip_button").click(inputData);
  $("#get_data_button").click(contractBalance);
  $("#fund_contract_button").click(fundContract);
  $("#withdraw_fund_button").click(withdrawFund);


})

// extra function starts here

function withdrawFund(){
  contractInstance.methods.withdrawAll().send();
}

function fundContract(){
  var fundAmount = $("#fund_contract_value").val();
  var config = {
    value: web3.utils.toWei(fundAmount,"ether")
  }
  contractInstance.methods.fundContract().send(config)
  .on("transactionHash", function(hash){
    console.log(hash);
  })
  .on("confirmation", function(confirmationNr){
    console.log(confirmationNr);
  })
  .on("receipt", function(receipt){
    console.log(receipt);
  })
}


function inputData(){
  var betAmount = $("#bet_input").val();
  var config = {
    value: web3.utils.toWei(betAmount,"ether")
  }
  contractInstance.methods.flipCoin().send(config)
  .on("transactionHash", function(hash){
    console.log(hash);
  })
  .on("confirmation", function(confirmationNr){
    console.log(confirmationNr);
  })
  .on("receipt", function(receipt){
    console.log(receipt);
if(receipt.events.flipCoinData.returnValues[1] === false){
alert("You have lost");
}

  })
}

function contractBalance(){

  contractInstance.methods.getContractBalance().call().then(function(res){
    $("#jackpot_output").text(web3.utils.fromWei(res) + " Ether");
  })
}
```

Comment: Change `console.log(receipt)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4))`, and you will get the answer to your question.

Comment: Tried, didn't work

Comment: It did not give you the answer??? What did it give you?

Comment: I changed the position of emit, I added it before the return syntax and it worked.    `code` function flipCoin() public payable costs(0.1 ether) returns(bool)  {
    require(msg.value <= contractBalance,"The contract doesn't have enough balance");
  bool result;
  uint chance;
  chance = now % 2;
  if (chance == 0){
      contractBalance += msg.value;
    result = false;
  }
  else if ( chance == 1){
      contractBalance -= msg.value;
      msg.sender.transfer(msg.value*2);
    result = true;
  }
  emit flipCoinData(msg.value,result);
  return result;
}

Comment: Holy @#$%. You placed a piece of code after the `return` statement??? I think you may wanna start with some learning of basic programming concepts, before jumping to all of what you're trying above.

Comment: With console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4)), I was getting the same response ( receipt ) without events

Comment: Yeah, I started coding from last 3 weeks, so didn't know about this. Does the function exit after the return statement? Please tell me if there is any good website to start with

Comment: Yes. And it is stated: "The function returns" (after the `return` statement, as implied from the name of this keyword).